# How to override some summernote module function?

Tags: jquery, overriding, summernote

How could I override some of summernote module function?

summernote source is here:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/summernote/summernote/develop/dist/summernote.js

I need override this function:

```
this.createItemTemplates = function (hintIdx, items) {
  var hint = hints[hintIdx];
  return items.map(function (item, idx) {
    var $item = $('<div class="note-hint-item"/>');
    $item.append(hint.template ? hint.template(item) : item + '');
    $item.data({
      'index': hintIdx,
      'item': item
    });

    if (hintIdx === 0 && idx === 0) {
      $item.addClass('active');
    }
    return $item;
  });
};
```

to this:

```
this.createItemTemplates = function (hintIdx, items) {
  var hint = hints[hintIdx];
  return items.map(function (item, idx) {
    var $item = $('<div class="note-hint-item"/>');
    $item.append(hint.template ? hint.template(item) : item + '');
    $item.data({
      'index': hintIdx,
      'item': item
    });

    return $item;
  });
};
```

maybe it is some jQuery OOP basic, but I back-ender and do not know how.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but try: `$.summernote.hintPopover.createItemTemplates = function() {};` or `$.summernote.options.modules.hintPopover.createItemTemplates = function() {};`.

Comment: when I do `console.log($.summernote.options.modules.hintPopover)` I got function dump, when I do `console.log($.summernote.options.modules.hintPopover.createItemTemplates)` i get undefined, maybe I have to override all module and assigin it to `$.summernote.options.modules.hintPopover`